# how to bind array data to select option

Tags: javascript

i have array data it call "provinsi" i got array on console like normal array

here's my code

```
 <select id="select">
      <option value="default">default</option>
 </select>
 <script>
        console.log(provinsi)
        var select = document.getElementById("select");

        for(var i = 0; i < provinsi.length; i++)
        {
            var option = document.createElement("option"),
                txt = document.createTextNode(provinsi[i]);
            option.appendChild(txt);
            option.setAttribute("value",provinsi[i]);
            select.insertBefore(option,select.lastChild);
        }
    </script>
```

but i got result like this 
[image]

here's my console "provinsi"
[image]
any suggest ? thanks before

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: sorry forgot about that, i need select option data is my array it call "provinsi"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w83b7j6x/1/ - seems to work for me. Where are you defining `provinsi`?

Comment: i use on blade.php laravel , i defining from leaflet, and i use the code to bind data to option in blade inside tag <script>

Comment: The code by itself is working fine. Can you show how you are populating the variable provinsi

Comment: Your code is working.
Is it possible this code is executing before the DOM is loaded and `option` is undefined when this is run?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the DOM is not ready yet.

Try putting your code inside IIFE.

```
(function() {
    // the DOM will be available here

    console.log(provinsi)
    var select = document.getElementById("select");

    for(var i = 0; i < provinsi.length; i++)
    {
        var option = document.createElement("option"),
            txt = document.createTextNode(provinsi[i]);
        option.appendChild(txt);
        option.setAttribute("value",provinsi[i]);
        select.insertBefore(option,select.lastChild);
    }

})();
```

** Just to clarify as @karthick mentioned, make sure the script is loaded at the end of the body tag.

Comment: you need to use DOMContentLoaded to tell dom is ready not iife

Comment: @karthick I don't must anything. you can do that in iife as long as the script is loaded at the end of the body tag. Edit: Actually, This is faster to execute than an onload handler because this waits only for the DOM to be ready, not for all images to load. And, this works in every browser.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work happy coding :) Note: change your provinces array with orginal values

```js
$(document).ready(()=> {
  let provinces = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4" ]
  $.each(provinces, function(key,item) {
  $("#select").append(new Option(item, key));
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
      <option value="default">default</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The DOM may not have finished loading when your script is run. You should run your function on `DOMContentLoaded`.

```html
<select id="select">
      <option value="default">default</option>
 </select>
 <script>
  var provinsi = ["test1", "test2"];
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    //DOM fully loaded and parsed
    var select = document.getElementById("select");

        for(var i = 0; i < provinsi.length; i++)
        {
            var option = document.createElement("option"),
                txt = document.createTextNode(provinsi[i]);
            option.appendChild(txt);
            option.setAttribute("value",provinsi[i]);
            select.insertBefore(option,select.lastChild);
        }
  });
        
    </script>
<script>

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jquery each` function for `looping`

**Javascript Code:**

```
var makers = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Toyota'}, 
  {id: 2, name: 'Nissan'}, 
  {id: 3, name: 'Honda'}
]
    
$.each(makers, function (index, item) {
   $('#makers-listing').append(`<option value="${item.id}">${item.name}</option>`);
});
```

**Html Code:**

```
<select id="makers-listing">
    <option>Select Maker</option> <!-- This is default value -->
</select>
```